# I don't get the meaning of the phrase in bold clearly?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> At night he went home and there was Lucile - less like a flower, but still silent, fragrant, hopeful. He said to her: "you will never have anything more than you have now, Lucile, do you realize that?" she replied: "I don't want anything more to dust and take care of!" Once he said:"When you were a girl you dreamed that you 'd have  things different, didn't you, Lucile?" she said: "my dear, **all that poor girl knew how to dream was just about having things!**" He cried: "What do you want most of anything in this world?" she considered and answered: " I want you to be as happy as I am."

Dose it mean that even when she was a young girl she did not care about having things?

This passage is from a short story named: "The Woman" by Zona Gale.

the name of the book which this story come from is: Discovering fiction: 1 chapter 12

Answer (score 1):

A girl who is very poor owns very few things. Girls in that situation therefore fantasize (dream) exclusively about owning material things.

It's implied that the things they fantasize about owning are not very expensive or special. Because they have little experience with ownership, riches, or luxury, they can't imagine having genuinely nice luxuries, nor do they fantasize about nice circumstances.

Comment: Sorry instead of "girl" I had written "girls" I am really sorry Now I edited it.

Comment: I disagree with the second half of this answer. I believe that 'she' was trying to say that the girl didn't know how to dream about lofty ideals, _non-material things_, such as 'world peace' or 'true love' for example.

Comment: @MikeBrockington That is also a valid interpretation and makes sense to me as well.